# Invalid gz file after splitting

Tags: python, gzip

I have a gz file of 500MB and I have split it as follows

```
split -b 100m "file.gz" "file1.gz.part-"
```

after splitting the following files are obtained

```
file1.gz.part-aa
file1.gz.part-ab
file1.gz.part-ac
file1.gz.part-ad
file1.gz.part-ae
```

I am trying to iterate over objects in gzip file using gzip as follows

```
 with gzip.open(filename) as f:
      for line in f:
```

This is working for `file1.gz.part-aa` but for the other 4 parts I am getting

> Not a gzipped file error

Comment: Just for TESTING, join (with `cat`) the files back to one and see if you can unzip them from the command line. If this works then they are not corrupted and it's an implementation error. Otherwise there's a corruption for some unexplicable reason.

Comment: Take a new look at my answer please, I've edited it right now.

Comment: You could concatenate them in a (shell) subprocess, and read its output from a pipe.

Comment: can you elaborate

Comment: `from subprocess import Popen, PIPE` plus `p = Popen('cat file1.gz*', close_fds=True, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)` Plus something like
    `xxx = p.stdin.read()`

Answer (score 1):

A gzip file has a header that identifies it as a gzip file. After splitting, only the first file will have this header. Rejoin the files before processing.

Comment: I need to process them individually .. is there a way to copy the header to every file?

Comment: Even if you did, you've still broken the compression somewhere in the middle of the stream. You will not be happy with the results.

Comment: In that case can we somehow split the files based on no of lines rather than size and copy the header to every file?

Comment: Why not just generate multiple files in the first place?

Comment: because in my case  the generation of gz file is unfortunately very time consuming step

Comment: The solution is just inverting the order in which `split` and `gzip` are applied...

Answer (score 1):

You can `split` before you `gzip`:

```
split -l 300000 "file.txt" "tweets1.part-"
      ^ every 300000 lines
```

Notice that the input of `split` is **NOT** a `*.gz` file but the original line-oriented file.

Then `gzip` every part separately:

```
gzip tweets1.part-*
```

This will also remove the parts (there's a `gzip` option to keep them).

In python, you can now consume each part separately.

Comment: In the first place , I have file.gz available .. I want to iterate over objects in splitted files only.

Comment: small catch .. after doing this somehow I am not able to iterate over the json object which is the basic unit of my file ..

Comment: Nice :( That's because the JSON object spans across all files, so splitting by lines breaks the JSON syntax. At least we tried! To correctly split a JSON object you need to parse it and render it in pieces, which is way more difficult than can be discussed in a comment.